# Ecto: Order preloaded data in collection with has_many association

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Let's say I have this for fetching all threads:

```
Thread |> Thread.ordered |> Repo.all |> Repo.preload([:posts])
```

How could I provide an order_by clause for `:posts`? I can't seem to locate anything in the documentation that references `Ecto.Repo.preload/1`, so none of the provided examples appear helpful for figuring out how to use this syntax properly.

Comment: Check out the "Preload queries" section here: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3. It describes exactly what you want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Ecto.Query](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html) module makes it really easy to also apply certain queries to things like preloading.

The way we achieve this is by **passing a query** into the preload function, which then restricts the results of the preload to that query.

For example, in your case:

```
import Ecto.Query # => Needed to use the ecto query helpers

Thread 
|> Thread.ordered 
|> Repo.all 
|> Repo.preload([posts: (from p in Post, order_by: p.published_at)])
```

(assuming you have a published at field on the posts)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works! I also needed to `import Ecto.Query` if anyone else discovers this thread and has the same issue.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore.  Now you need to write a query, then pin that query when you pass it in to preload, like so:

`comments_query = from c in Comment, order_by: c.popularity, limit: 5
Repo.all from p in Post, preload: [comments: ^comments_query]`

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3-preload-queries

Comment: Would this be possible if you wanted to order by a column that is in another table (via a join?)