# Order records that are preloaded with Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I would like to order some records based on an attribute that belongs to the record. Take a look at the following code.

```
project = Repo.get!(Project, id)
          |> Repo.preload(rows: :images)
```

This of course queries the `Project` for the given `id`. The `Project` is not what I'm interested in ordering. I'd like to order the `Images` that I'm preloading by an integer I have on the Image record. How would I do this with Phoenix? If anyone can guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43330145/320615

Comment: Thanks @Dogbert that looks perfect for my needs.